How to Use AGDK GameActivity or NativeActivity for Android Game Development in Visual Studio 2022?
I want to develop an Android game using AGDE in Visual Studio 2022. What are the steps required to use the AGDK GameActivity? Additionally, if I choose not to use GameActivity, how can I use NativeActivity instead?
I want to separate the game engine and the game application, similar to the AGDE sample "teapot," and make it compatible with both Windows and Android.
I have already followed the steps outlined in the following links:
https://developer.android.com/games/agde/quickstart
https://developer.android.com/games/agde/adapt-existing-project
I downloaded AGDK and copied it to C:\libs, then configured the Additional Include Directory and Additional Dependencies. The directories I set are C:\libs\agdk-libraries-2023.3.0.0\include and C:\libs\agdk-libraries-2023.3.0.0\libs.
